# PHP-form-builder-class not working

Tags: php, forms, apache

I am trying to implement Php-form-builder class but I get

`Fatal error: Class 'Form' not found in C:\wamp\www\project\admin\newpost.php on line 18`

I am running apache 2.4.2 with php 5.4.3 please anyone with idea on how to get this running?

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("../PFBC/Form.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
$form = new Form("layout_grid", 500);

$form->configure(array(
    "view" => new View_Grid(array(2, 1, 3))
));
$form->addElement(new Element_Hidden("form", "layout_grid"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Title:", "Title"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("First Name:", "FirstName"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Last Name:", "LastName"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("City:", "City"));
$form->addElement(new Element_State("State:", "State"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Zip Code:", "ZipCode"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Button);
$form->render();
?>

</body>
</html

>
```

Comment: Check the path, failing that check permissions. It's unlikely there's another issue causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have problem with `namespaces`,

try:

`$form = new PFBC\Form("layout_grid", 500);`

Do you have PFBC version for PHP5.3?

`$form->addElement(new PFBC\Element\Hidden("form", "elements"));`

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter way of achieving pretty much the same thing. If you are using `PHP >= 5.3`
you just add the "use" keyword in at the top of the page, just after the session_start()
thus:

`use PFBC\Form;`

`use PFBC\Element;`

After that you just go ahead and build your form as you have already done, you won't need to add the extra PFBC\ in each line.
It is all in the documentation.
If you are using any version of php prior to `5.3` you need to download the alternative package.